# CLEAR COLUMNS Definition

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'am confused on this function `clear columns`. Some one can explain to me this one.

I'am using this in my script.

```
    clear columns
COLUMN temp_in_statement new_value str_in_statement
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LISTAGG('''' || MONTHCOVERED || ''' AS ' || to_char(MONTHCOVERED,'MONDDYYYY'),',')
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY MONTHCOVERED) AS temp_in_statement 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT trunc(MONTHCOVERED) as MONTHCOVERED FROM bbsm_aaa where trunc(MONTHCOVERED) between '01-AUG-19' and '31-OCT-19');
```

Is there specific column/s that are cleared on this? Or all columns that I assigned was also deleted?

Comment: please mention what formatting or settings have u provided before running this query ? if there is no formatting or settings provided then you clear col is useless in this case as it will not delete or erase any contents from table but its just the formatting which will be shown after running the query..

Answer (score -1):

`HELP` is there for a reason :)

```
SQL> help clear

 CLEAR
 -----

 Resets or erases the current value or setting for the specified option.

 CL[EAR] option ...

 where option represents one of the following clauses:
     BRE[AKS]
     BUFF[ER]
     COL[UMNS]
     COMP[UTES]
     SCR[EEN]
     SQL
     TIMI[NG]


SQL>
```

This isn't related to columns' contents, but the way they are *formatted* in SQL*Plus. Have a look at this example:

First, set some columns' settings using the `col` command:

```
SQL> col empno format 9999
SQL> col ename format a5
SQL> col sal format 999g990d00
SQL>
SQL> select empno, ename, sal from emp where rownum < 4;

EMPNO ENAME         SAL
----- ----- -----------
 7369 SMITH      920,00
 7499 ALLEN    1.600,00
 7521 WARD     1.250,00
```

Now, clear those settings and see the difference:

```
SQL> clear col
columns cleared
SQL> select empno, ename, sal from emp where rownum < 4;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH             920
      7499 ALLEN            1600
      7521 WARD             1250

SQL>
```

As you can see, values in those columns weren't affected - only the way they are displayed.

Comment: On my script, I used `clear columns`, what columns are affected? I'm so confused. @Littlefoot

Comment: No columns in particular (if you mean their contents). It is related to the way they are displayed. I have edited my answer and added an example; have a look, please.

Comment: I disagree, @Andrew (but you have the right to express your opinion, of course). Why do I disagree? Because of their comment posted a few minutes ago, and contents I added to my answer.

Comment: just want to understand why didnt u added the the answer or given an example  related to the query given in the question ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is **you** who doesn't understand the question, @Andrew. It is not about `select distinct listagg ...`, but SQL Plus `clear` command. Do you use SQL Plus? If not, huh, then this discussion is quite useless as you - obviously - don't understand what I am talking about.

Comment: did u see the first comment of @Ace ? he is asking something and what answer u have provided is it related ?

Comment: @Andrew, `clear col` will remove formatting of all columns that were previously formatted using `col` command (if that's what you ask). OP's code doesn't show any `col` commands so - `clear col` is pretty much useless in this example.

Comment: I got the point Sir @Littlefoot, I'm just confused if i have deleted some value on other column that i didn't used.

Comment: Once again: **no values in any column is deleted** with `clear col` SQL Plus command. It doesn't affect values stored in the table, only the way you see them in SQL Plus.

Comment: exactly correct @Littlefoot i agree ..this is the first question we should have ask Ace otherwise i believe just mentioning the answer with general example he could not have understood like he is confused now also with clear column and deleting the contents

Comment: I posted an example, @Andrew; didn't I?

Comment: I really appreciated you both guys.

Comment: No problem; I hope it helped, @Ace.